# Pass entity type through method in EF

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0, generics, entity

Hi I want to produce a generic linq query that gets the required drop down information from the database. I want to be able to specify the entity i want to get data from within the context.

e.g.

```
public IEnumerable<T> getListOfDropdowns(int assignId, TEntity entityname)
{
    return context.<TEntity>.Where(x => x.assignId == 1);
}
```

All lookup tables contain the same properties. eg. ID and Description.

I now have

```
public IQueryable<T> GetLookupByContractorTwo<TEntity>(int contractorId, TEntity entity)
{
return _context.Set<entity>().Find(contractorId);
}
```

But I get an error saying entity cannot be found and missing a referencbut i am unable to find the reference.

Comment: Which EF version are you using? DbSet is generic, isn't it?

Comment: This: `return _context.Set<entity>().Find(contractorId);` makes no sense... It should be: `return _context.Set<TEntity>().Find(contractorId);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetLookupByContractorTwo<TEntity>(int contractorId)
{
    return _context.Set<TEntity>().Find(contractorId);
}
```

You don't need to pass the Type as a parameter if you're using generics.

---

## Edit

You probably want to do this:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetLookupByContractorTwo<TEntity>(int contractorId)
{
  return _context.Set(typeof(TEntity)).Find(contractorId);
}
```

Comment: Then how do I know which data i need from the dropdownlist since every set of dropdowns has its own table?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Can you add the code you're trying to use to fill the dropdowns?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Find`method instead. `Find` uses the primary key to search.
Another good thing about `Find` is that it will perform a round-trip to the database only if the entity is not found in the context.

This should do the trick:

```
var result = context.Set<TEntity>().Find(assignId);
```